# how to fix this problem "Undefined variable: category"?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am getting this error message and I don't know what is wrong with my code.

CategoriesController.php

```
class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
       $categories = Category::all();

       return view('admin.categories.index', ['categories' => $categories]);
    }
}
```

index.blade.php

```
foreach ($categories as $category)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$category->idcat}}</td>
        <td>{{$category->cat}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="edit.html" class="fa fa-pencil"></a> 
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-remove"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
endforeach
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not how the blade templating engine works:
You should use @foreach @endforeach in your view:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
          <tr>
            <td>{{$category->idcat}}</td>
            <td>{{$category->cat}}</td>
            <td><a href="edit.html" class="fa fa-pencil"></a> <a href="#" class="fa fa-remove"></a></td>
          </tr>
@endforeach
```